# New posting notification for certain member group

Tags: members, module, forum

We have a developed a new academic forum on our site and would like to generate an email to the academic members alerting them that a new posting has been made. I realise that Administrators and Moderators can receive these notifications but there's no apparent way to identify a particular member group other than thses.
I have so far tries Postmaster and MX Notify but sadly neither of these will enable me to monitor forum entries, only channel entries. I was wondering if anyone has found a way around this issue?

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Check out this add-on I've developed a real while ago: [Forum Notifier](https://github.com/intoeetive/forum_notifier)

If it does not do the job you need, then you probably need something more or less custom built.

Comment: Hi Yuri, looks good have gor an error though: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Creating default object from empty value
Filename: forum_notifier/mcp.forum_notifier.php
Line Number: 59

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to support this add-on free of charge. If it's working, just ignore the error.